# Does PHP parse through code with // comments or line breaks more quickly?

Tags: php, performance, comments

Which does php parse more quickly:

1. `//`
2. `//`
3. `//`
4. `//`
5. `//`

or:

1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. 

In other words, is it extremely marginal the speed it takes to parse a `//` comment, as compared to the time it takes to pass through an empty line?

Comment: It's almost certainly marginal, yes, and it should be irrelevant -  you should be using a bytecode cache such as APC if you're worried about parse time.

Comment: If you are worried about this, PHP is the wrong language for your app.

Comment: @John3136 But it's commendable for a programmer to be mindful of efficiency, even if this is situation is extreme. :)

Comment: @jimp If someone's worrying about this sort of thing, they're likely paralyzed by indecision at the simplest coding issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree, but I read the question with a tone of curiosity.

Comment: 20+ years as a programmer and it's never crossed my mind to worry about the parsing time of a comment. At worst it will be a teeny tiny overhead as the file is parsed - it wil pale into insignificance compared to the actual functional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments will be parsed into individual nodes in the parse tree, but the adjacent whitespace of newlines will result in just one node in the parse tree.

So the technical answer is the whitespace will parse faster, but it is marginal and completely negligible in just about any PHP script. Use an op cache, which will toss out the comments and whitespace, if compile times actually matter to you.

Answer (score 1):

`//` is still three or four characters. `//\n\r` or `//\n` depending on OS. But new line is just two or one character `\n\r` or `\n`.

Modern interpreters are smart enough to optimise it. You should focus more on Code readability instead.